# Can’t autologin with GDM

Tags: arch-linux, gdm

So I don’t understand because this always worked for me but after a new Arch Linux install I’m always prompted the GDM login screen.

I enabled autologin through gnome-control-center (“Connexion automatique” toggle)

[image]

which I believe updated */etc/gdm/custom.conf*

```
# GDM configuration storage

[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
#WaylandEnable=false

AutomaticLoginEnable=True
AutomaticLogin=mathieu

[security]

[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
#Enable=true
```

But this configuration still gets me the login screen on boot. Did I miss something? I’m using GDM 3.30.2

Here is the content of */var/lib/AccountsService/users/mathieu*

```
[User]
Language=
XSession=
Icon=/home/mathieu/.face
SystemAccount=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it seems the root cause of the issue was this log from *gnome-shell*:

> Failed to create backend: Could not find a primary drm kms device

I don't know why, but [enabling KMS during the initramfs stage](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_mode_setting#Early_KMS_start) solved the issue.

---

Enabling [Intel graphics fastboot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Fastboot) seems to do the job as well.